# how to get each country stats to the material-ui table from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am new to react and material-ui So I don't know much about how to do it all if someone can help me to resolve this...

i am trying to create covid19 react app I have done a little and there is something left.
in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av0e3.png) i'm trying to fetch all the related data like confirmed, recovered and deaths for each country but the problem is I tried everything but I could not succeed... Maybe what I'm doing is wrong and I don't know what the right way is...

**fetch api**

**index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api'

export const fetchData = async (country) => {
    let changeableUrl = url
    
    if (country) {
    changeableUrl = `${url}/countries/${country}`
  }

  try {
      const {data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths}} = await axios.get(changeableUrl)

      return { confirmed, 
               recovered,
               deaths
            }
  }
      catch 
      (error) {
          return error
      }
  }

  // export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/daily.json');
  
  //     return data.map(({ positive, recovered, death, dateChecked: date }) => ({ confirmed: positive, recovered, deaths: death, date }));
  //   } catch (error) {
  //     return error;
  //   }
  // };

export const fetchCountries = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: { countries } } = await axios.get(`${url}/countries`);

    return countries.map((country) => country.name);

  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

TableCom component where i created a material-ui table in FormControl

**TableCom.js**

```
import { FormControl, makeStyles, Paper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { fetchCountries } from '../FetchDataFromApi/index'

// import { AutoSizer } from 'react-virtualized'

// const useStyles = makeStyles({})

export const Countries = ({ handleCountryChange, data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths}, country}) => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        (async () => {
          const fetchedData = await fetchCountries();
          setCountries(fetchedData)
        })()
      }, [])

    // const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <FormControl>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell align='right'>Country</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align='right'>Total Infected</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align='right'>Total Recoverd</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align='right'>Total Deaths</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {countries.map((country) => {
                            return (
                                <TableRow 
                                key = {country.name}
                                onClick = {() => handleCountryChange(country)}
                                >
                                <TableCell>{country}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{country.confirmed}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{country}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{country}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

and then App.js from where sending data and country as props to `TableCpm.js`

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Appbar } from './components/pageOne/Appbar'
import { Cards } from './components/pageOne/Cards'
import { fetchData } from './components/FetchDataFromApi'
import { CountryPicker } from './components/pageOne/CountryPicker'
import { Countries } from './components/pageOne/TableCom'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetchData();
      setData(fetchedData)
    })()
  }, [])

  const handleCountryChange = async (country) => {
    const data = await fetchData(country)
    
    setCountry({data, country: country})
  }


  return (
    <>
    <Appbar />
    <Cards data = {data} />
    {/* <CountryPicker handleCountryChange = {handleCountryChange}/> */}
    <Countries handleCountryChange = {handleCountryChange} data = {data} country = {country}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is the only problem you are facing is not getting the results rendered? Can you `console.log` and check if the `fetchedData` is fetched correctly?

Comment: @theWellHopeErr is right when I check what is return by the api url https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries, it's only returning a list of countries with their iso name.

Comment: The only way to get data for each countries is by one of the three api end points :
https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed 
https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths 
https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered
all these endpoints return the same data (hmmm that's interesting).
But the api response is an array of province/state not countries.
I've made this little sandbox to help you [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-babbage-efuj8?file=/src/FetchAPI.js)